# Why does changing variable of integration change the result of a definite integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've defined the following two very similar recursive functions:

```
ET1[n_, x_] := If[n == 0, 0, 
               Integrate[(ET1[n - 1, x]), {z, 0, x}] + 
                Integrate[(y + ET1[n - 1, y]), {y, x, 1}]]

ET2[n_, x_] := If[n == 0, 0,
                Integrate[(ET2[n - 1, x]), {y, 0, x}] +
                 Integrate[(y + ET2[n - 1, y]), {y, x, 1}]]
```

The only difference is whether the first `Integrate` uses `z` or `y`, and the integrand includes neither of those variables. I don't have any idea why this should affect the result; in either case the integral should come out to `x * ET[n-1, x]` (the reason I'm not just writing that out in the first place is that I think the integral makes the logic clearer). For `n=1` and `n=2`, the two functions in fact appear to agree for all `x` between 0 and 1. But on Mathematica 10.4.1, I'm getting that `ET1[3,0] = 13/12` while `ET2[3,0] = 7/8`. For what it's worth, if I replace the first `Integrate` with what it should evaluate to (i.e. `x * ET[n-1, x]`), then it gives the same answer as `ET1`.

What gives?

Comment: I took the version 10 tag off, since this happens on other versions as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a semi-trace by inactivating `Integrate`:

```
Block[{Integrate = Inactive[Integrate]}, ET1[3, 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{Integrate = Inactive[Integrate]}, ET2[3, 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Near the beginning of the second lines, some dy in the first integral are dz in the second. They give different results:

[image: Mathematica graphics]